# Slurping TCP Echo Server In Nodejs

Tags: node.js, tcp

I tried to make a simple TCP echo server that first reads all input before it sends out a copy of it.

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');

    //socket.pipe(socket)

    socket.UsrData='';
    socket.on('data', function(chunk){
            socket.UserData+=chunk;
    });
    socket.on('end', function(){
            console.log('end');
            socket.end(socket.UserData);
    });
});
server.listen(1337, 'localhost');
```

Now if I send a file to this server with

```
nc  -q0 localhost 1337 </etc/profile
```

the server crashes with:

```
end
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
    at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:364:12)
    at Socket.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:563:10)
    at Socket.end (net.js:509:31)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/petr/f/learn/nodejs/echo.js:20:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

How do I fix it?

(
I'd like the server to work like

```
socat  TCP4-LISTEN:1337,reuseport,fork EXEC:'./slurp'
```

where `./slurp` is something like:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
inp=$(cat)
printf '%s\n' "$inp"
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a Node.js socket closes itself as soon as it notices that the other end of the connection has initiated a disconnect.  So there is no opportunity for your server to send data to the client.  By the time the 'end' event fires in your program, your socket has already been closed and you get an error because the program tries to send the collected `UserData` into the closed socket.

To get the behaviour you want, you must tell your socket to not close when it sees that the other end has initiated a disconnect.  Do that by passing an options object as the first argument to `net.createServer`, where that object contains an option named `allowHalfOpen` with a value of `true`, like this:

```
    net.createServer( { allowHalfOpen: true }, function(socket) { ... } );
```

(Your existing connect-handler function becomes the second argument to that call.)  After you do this, your socket will remain open and the program will be able to send the accumulated `UserData`.

For details see https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener